# calculating weighted sum of two columns with weights as two other columns

Tags: r, dplyr

consider the following dataset including NAs

```
df <- data.frame(x1=c(3, 6, 9, NA),
                 w1=c(0.25, 1, 0.90, 0),
                 x2=c(2, NA, 4, 8),
                 w2=c(0.75, 0, 0.10, 1))
```

I would like to calculate a new column as `weighted_sum=x1.w1 + x2.w2` with `dplyr`, `mutate`  and `weighted.mean` but I do not have any idea how to set variables and weights and I could not find exact this issue under other quastions. The result should be like as following and NAs should not be regarded in sum.

```
  x1   w1   x2   w2 weighted_sum
  3    0.25  2 0.75         2.25
  6    1.00 NA 0.00         6.00
  9    0.90  4 0.10         8.50
  NA   0.00  8 1.00         8.00
```

Thankfull for any help!

Comment: Could also `df %>% mutate(weighted_sum = rowSums(cbind(x1*w1, x2*w2), na.rm = TRUE))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(weighted_sum = sum((x1*w1), (x2*w2), na.rm = TRUE))
# -------------------------------------------------------------------------

#      x1    w1    x2    w2 weighted_sum
#     <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>
# 1     3  0.25     2  0.75   2.25
# 2     6  1       NA  0      6   
# 3     9  0.9      4  0.1    8.5 
# 4    NA  0        8  1      8
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution with base R for an abstract number of columns (x1, w1, x2, w2, x3, w3, x4, w4, etc...)

```
Reduce(`+`, sapply(split.default(replace(df, is.na(df), 0), gsub('\\D+', '', names(df))), function(i) i[1] * i[2]))
#[1] 2.25 6.00 8.50 8.00
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution in base R that works for any number of columns and weights:

```
df$weighted_sum <- mapply(function(x,y,z) sum(y[x,]*z[x,], na.rm = TRUE),
                         x = 1:nrow(df),
                         MoreArgs = list(
                         y = df[, grepl("^w", names(df))],
                        z = df[, grepl("^x", names(df))]))
```

**Output**

```
#  x1   w1 x2   w2 weighted_sum
#  3 0.25  2 0.75         2.25
#  6 1.00 NA 0.00         6.00
#  9 0.90  4 0.10         8.50
# NA 0.00  8 1.00         8.00
```